# why atlassian bamboo can deploy war files bigger than 50MB?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, bamboo

when i deploy my war from my tomcat manager it dosen't works because the limit is 50MB and my war is bigger.

when i deploy my war from atlassian bamboo platform it works ... ??

someone have suggestions for explain it ?

thanks